# Timber Wordpress child menu

Tags: timber

I am looking for a way to display all child pages of the current page, similar to the wp_page_list function, but in Timber (Twig).

I know I can either add to the context via a query, or simply wrap the worpdress function in a timber function.

Either method I am struggling with and would appreciate some syntax guidance.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how ideal this is, but it does the trick

```
{% for item in menu.get_items %}
  {% if item.get_children and post.link == item.url %}
    <ul class="jumbo-menu {{ post.slug | replace({'-data':''})}}">
      {% for child in item.get_children %}
        <li><a href="{{child.get_link}}">{{child.title}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing `post.link` and `item.url`, you could also use `item.current`. So that would be `{% if item.children and item.current %}` then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display child pages without using a WordPress menu? So without the `get_items` method? The children of a given page are available via the post object, irrespective of any menu functions.

```
{% for child in post.children %}        
   <li><a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This assumes `$context['post'] = new TimberPost();` in your controller.